# SpServices GetListItems Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, compatibility, spservices

We have a problem related to the Compatibility settings on the IE browser and SPServices GetListItems.

At VA, we have several scripts using SPServices  (jQuery/HTML5) which work fine as long as the Compatibility View Settings on the (IE) browser is set to either of the following:

“va.gov” is added to “Websites added to Compatibility View”, and/or,
“Display intranet sites in Compatibility View” is checked.

However, the new CIO site is forcing everyone to remove everything in the Compatibility View Setting of their browsers before being redirected to the CIO site.

But with this new IE compatibility setting the SPServices GetListItems stops talking to SharePoint!!  And as soon as we reset the compatibility view settings to any of the above it works.

We are using jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js.

The following is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://vaww.oed.wss.va.gov/process/Public/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://vaww.oed.wss.va.gov/process/Public/jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listProcesses = "{4AB19761-E153-4DB0-AD5A-6E9A42571488}";
    var spSiteURL = "http://vaww.oed.wss.va.gov/process";
    var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Process_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>AAA</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
var queryView = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Process_x0020_Map_x0020_Diagram' /><FieldRef Name='Process_x0020_Map_x0020_Diagram_' /></ViewFields>";
    $().SPServices({
        siteUrl: spSiteURL,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: listProcesses,
        CAMLViewFields: queryView,
        CAMLQuery: query,
        async: false,       
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I  added siteUrl and it didn’t help. Alerting on “xData.responseXML.xml” generates an Undefined.  Again, as soon as we change the Compatibility on the IE browser everything works.

Would greatly appreciate any help and your advice, we have looked everywhere to no avail and are totally stuck.

Thank you,

Tony

Comment: I'm using the same script versions as you, and am in IE 11 on our intranet. I clearly my compatibility settings and my SPServices still runs. Maybe try using a relative path, like `src="/process/..."`?

Comment: I'd also recommend deleting the site url from your sample above. Government security best practice.